# how to change the integer value using call method in java?

Tags: java, integer, pass-by-reference

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    private static int call(int n) {
        n = n - 1;
        return n;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 5;
        call(n);
        System.out.println(n);//output is still 5;
    }
}
```

how to change the value of n using call method?
I did using void on call method like we use for integer array but that is also not working.

Comment: "how to change the value of n using call method?" If you want to change the value of `n`, you need to explicitly assign the result of `call(n)` to it, like this: `n = call(n);`  There is no other way.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you wrote `call(5)`?